# htaccess redirect form non www to www with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all website url without www to www website
on some server that i usually use i never got issue using this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

on this server url are redirect from not www to www but they lose query string

i try with curl from mac shell and it seems that 301 lose query sting

```
$ curl -I http://mywebsite.com/web/practice/?sbp=12
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 09:25:30 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/web/practice/
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 09:25:30 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Use the  `QSA` flag: `[R=301,L, QSA]`

Comment: with the space [R=301,L, QSA] it gave me a internal server error, removing the space  [R=301,L,QSA] it still does redirect without query string

Comment: Maybe the order matters, not sure. Can you try it with QSA first?

Comment: no it doesn't make any difference [R=301,QSA,L] or [QSA,R=301,L] just to be sure last line will be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

Comment: Is that the entire `.htaccess`?

Comment: no is not, there is compression, cache and 404, no specific redirect or other RewriteRule. I also try to delete all the rest and upload htaccess but nothing changes

Comment: Do you have access to ghost config? If so, enable trace to see what's happening.

Comment: No is a shared hosting, but if i'm sure is a bug or configuration issue i write to support